# How to make the “Use for Development" button in Xcode appear again?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I first connect an iOS device to Xcode, it appears under Devices in organizer and a "magical" button appears, “Use for Development".

When I click this and log into my apple developer account, Xcode creates a "magical" provisioning profile that lets me debug any app on the device, without a specifically created provisioning profile for that specific app. This is very useful.

This provisioning profile usually has a wildcard at the end. The problem is that even if I delete all the profiles on my iPad (under settings->profiles) the magic button doesn't appear again, as in, it knows I already activated it.

Now, in order to make it appear again I have a single option : to reset or update my iPad which in term deletes everything. This is a painful and lengthy process for such a small feature. Is there any other way to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask Xcode to add this device (even though it has already done this previously). This causes Xcode to obtain a new team development profile.

Comment: Thanks ! By add you meant to "Add to portal" BUT, I already tried that and it said I already added it so I went and removed it and then when it added it, it also created the iOS Team Provisioning profile.One more thing though as the profile only sits on device after this (no idea why) so you have to drag and drop it into your library so you can use it in Xcode.

Answer (score 6):

I had to right click on the device in the Organizer and select "Ignore Device" for the button to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Add device to your provisioning profile in member center -> Generate profile -> Download -> Double click when Xcode is open
√Solved